# Can't resolve hostname by ip address over nslookup

Tags: ubuntu, local-area-network, hostname, nslookup

I've got an Ubuntu Server on my LAN.
I can fully use it (samba, ssh, apache2, xmpp...) by using it's ip address.
But I want to use the hostname to connect (e.g. ssh). When I do a nslookup with the ip address of the server, the answer is: name = noname (which is NOT the server's hostname ;-)
Other hosts on the LAN are responding with the correct hostname.

Output of nslookup 10.0.0.24 (this is my ubuntu server): shows no hostname

```
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53
24.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa  name = noname.
```

Output of nslookup 10.0.0.21 (this is my raspberryPi): shows the right hostname.

```
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53
21.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa  name = retropie.
```

All hosts get their ip address over DHCP. So the hosts, who show their hostname correctly were never configured separately.

Comment: What is your DNS server and do you have admin rights to it?

Comment: Are you registered in the local server's DNS?

Comment: Of course I have admin rights to my server :)
I didn't set up an extra DNS Server. On my LAN there is only a router with connection to my ISP and a few other hosts. Those other hosts are a RaspberryPi and a Windows machine. Both show up the right hostnames when doing nslookup.

Comment: @Bert What do you mean with registering to my server's DNS ?

Comment: I'm trying to guess where they come from since it should normally be done through a DNS server.  Please provide a full output of one that works to clarify.

Comment: I suspect it's done in your router one way or another.

Comment: My router recognizes my server and any other host, but he doesn't get the hostname of m ubuntu server. However the router does get the hostname of the raspberryPi and my Windows PC. Full output of nslookup?

Comment: nslookup ... ish! install dig :)

Comment: @RedCricket on Ubuntu `dig` is included out of the box :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a small network and without the assumption that there is dns server on this network you can simply add the ip addresses to the local hosts file on each machine. I know this is a bit "old school" but it will be 100% solid and never fail.

The reason dns may failing is that your dhcp server may be providing dns settings for a dns server that either you do not control or one that does not get automatic updates from the dhcp system. If you add a static entry into your (dns server you control whose ip address is given out via dhcp) then you will get the correct nslookup from a cli from any machine on your network.

Comment: yes, it seems that ubuntu doesn't provide the hostname over DHCP by default. But because the rasberryPi does it, i search for a solution to also provide the hostname automatically for the DHCP-Server (router)

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic system for making your hostname known to the rest of the network. If you have a DHCP server (often on your router in home setups) that might know it (I can see that mine does, but I don't know the DHCP protocol well enough to know how it's done). If you want others to know what IP address a certain name corresponds to, you (typically) have to set up DNS.

Comment: I edited my Question: The router gets the corresponding hostnames automatically for all my hosts but my ubuntu machine(s)